# Is forcing T-SQL query to use parallelism OK?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, performance, optimization, parallelism, query-performance

It can be done by calling the trace flag 8649 in a query option.

`OPTION (QUERYTRACEON 8649)`

This trace flag causes the cost of the query to be 0, which will always be below the cost threshold for parallelism and therefore the query will be considered for a parallel plan.

Does attempting to force a T-SQL query to use parallelism in this way have any downsides?

[sample tutorial how to force parallelism](http://web.archive.org/web/20180404164406/http://sqlblog.com/blogs/paul_white/archive/2011/12/23/forcing-a-parallel-query-execution-plan.aspx)

Comment: You used the word "force", but as the previous sentence suggests, parallelism is only considered even with a zero cost threshold.

Comment: That's because of my edit to the question. I have made a further edit.

Comment: To be clear, the trace flag doesn't cause the cost of the query to be 0. Also, Adam Machanic talks about [downsides to 8649 as well](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/adam_machanic/archive/2013/07/11/next-level-parallel-plan-porcing.aspx).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It has one big downside that is stated at the end of that post:

> Even experts with decades of SQL Server experience and detailed
>   internal knowledge will want to be careful with this trace flag.  I
>   cannot recommend you use it directly in production unless advised by
>   Microsoft

Interesting to use when testing but not really for production.